# Asociar clave foránea (FK) en Laravel 5.1 usando Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, laravel

Mi duda es: no sé como hace Laravel 5.1 para traer correctamente una FK asociada a su respectiva tabla con Eloquent?

Suponiendo que hay una tabla cliente con los atributos id, nombre, id_tarjeta.

La consulta la hago en el modelo o en el controlador?

Comment: ¿Quieres indicar que un atributo es FK o ya lo tienes indicado y quieres obtener esa FK?

Comment: Hola Malkev, lo que quiero es obtener esa fk, osea que al listar los clientes antes de aparecerme el id de la tarjeta, que aparezca el valor del campo "name" de la tarjeta asociada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTA: La respuesta está totalmente basada en la documentación y el código de Laravel:
[Documentación: Eloquent - Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships)
[Código: Eloquent - Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php)

---

Aunque desconozco el tipo de relación, voy a asumir OneToOne en esta ocasión, no debería variar mucho (salvo los métodos y tal vez las llaves) en caso que sea otro tipo.

Modelo cliente:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cliente extends Model
{
    /**
     * Obtener las tarjetas del cliente.
     */
    public function tarjeta()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Tarjeta');
    }
}
```

Modelo tarjeta:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tarjeta extends Model
{
    /**
     * Obtener el cliente dueño de la tarjeta.
     */
    public function cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente', 'id_tarjeta');
    }
}
```

Respondiendo a la pregunta si la consulta se hace en el modelo o en el controlador, la respuesta es: **depende del diseño de tu aplicación**.

Normalmente sería más adecuado hacer la consulta en el controlador, aunque dependiendo los patrones que uses, puede que sea mejor que lo hagas en un repositorio, servicio, job o en alguna otra parte de la aplicación (incluso en el mismo modelo).

En el controlador simplemente puedes llamar la relación así:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Cliente;

class AnyController extends Controller
{

    public function showCliente()
    {

    // Obtener la tarjeta asociada al cliente con id 1
    $tarjeta = Cliente::find(1)->tarjeta;

    // .....

    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Shaz por tu respuesta, se me debe haber pasado por alto la sección Eloquent - Relationships, gracias también por re-formular mi pregunta de una forma mas clara! Saludos

Comment: Si las respuesta te sirvió,  puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que trabajes con migraciones, ahí diseñas bien tu tabla y indicas los foreign.

```
Schema::table('posts', function ($table) {
  $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Comment: Gracias Leandro por tu pronta respuesta, no trabaje con migraciones por el echo de que la tabla ya esta diseñada y cargada con datos, pero para proyectos futuros lo haré!  Saludos Cordiales